# I have to filter files from Directory which matches the same file extension from ArrayList which I added

Tags: java

```
        String folderpath = "G:\\AE_IntegrationComp";
        //Above is Folder where is Different files are present
        
        List <String>filet = new ArrayList<String>();
        filet.add(".txt");
        filet.add(".doc");
        //extension which I added
        
        for(String str : filet)
        {
            
        }
        File directory = new File(folderpath);
        for(File list : directory.listFiles())
        {
            if(list.getName().contains(""))
            {
                System.out.println(list.getName());
            }
        }
```

I have to check if Directory is empty or not
if not,
file extension in Arraylist should matched with extensions Are available in Directory
and print files that matched

Comment: What's the output of your code snippet and why doesn't it meet your requirements?

Comment: You haven't asked a question.

Comment: If it found matched extension it will call particular method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you wanna do is:

1. Iterate through all files into a directory (which you have done)
2. Check if it has a certain extension (it ends with a certain string)
3. Print the file name if that matches.

```java
public class Main {

  // Here we have a constant containing the interesting file extensions
  public static final String[] extensions = new[] { ".txt", ".doc" };

  // This helper function will tell us whether 
  // a file has one of the interesting file extensions
  public static boolean matchesExtension(File file) {
    for(String ext : extensions) {
      if(file.getName().endsWith(ext)) { 
         return true; 
      }
    }
    return false;
  }


  public static void main(String[] args) {
        String folderpath = "G:\\AE_IntegrationComp";
        File directory = new File(folderpath);
        // Iterate through all files in the directory
        for(File file : directory.listFiles()){
            if(matchesExtension(file)){
                System.out.println(file.getName());
            }
        }

  }
}
```